# Objetos mascarados ao serem carregados. Isso impossibilita o pacote executar sua função? Como resolver?

Tags: r

Estou com problemas em executar alguns comandos de objetos de SpacialPoint DataFrame. Quando carrego os pacotes, dois deles aparecem mascarados por outros.

Sei que o mascaramento ocorre quando dois pacotes tem funções com os mesmos nomes.
Objetos mascarados impedem o pacote executar sua função? Isso impossibilita o pacote executar sua função? Como "desmascarar" esses pacotes para que eu possa usar corretamente os pacotes?

Aparece a seguinte mensagem:

```
> library("raster")

Attaching package: ‘raster’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:MASS’:

    area, select

> library("rgdal")
rgdal: version: 1.5-8, (SVN revision 990)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28
Path to GDAL shared files: C:/R/R-3.6.3/library/rgdal/gdal
GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
Loaded PROJ runtime: Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020, [PJ_VERSION: 631]
Path to PROJ shared files: C:/R/R-3.6.3/library/rgdal/proj
Linking to sp version:1.4-2
To mute warnings of possible GDAL/OSR exportToProj4() degradation,
use options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none") before loading rgdal.

> library("adehabitatHR")
Carregando pacotes exigidos: adehabitatMA
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'adehabitatMA':
  method                       from
  print.SpatialPixelsDataFrame sp  
  print.SpatialPixels          sp  

Attaching package: ‘adehabitatMA’

The following object is masked from ‘package:raster’:

    buffer

Ao executar o search() para ver quais funções estão mascaradas apareceu os seguintes:
> search()

 [1] ".GlobalEnv"           "package:ggplot2"      "package:VTrack"       "package:foreach"     
 [5] "package:adehabitatHR" "package:adehabitatLT" "package:adehabitatMA" "package:rgdal"       
 [9] "package:raster"       "package:sp"           "package:CircStats"    "package:boot"        
[13] "package:MASS"         "package:ade4"         "package:deldir"       "tools:rstudio"       
[17] "package:stats"        "package:graphics"     "package:grDevices"    "package:utils"       
[21] "package:datasets"     "package:methods"      "Autoloads"            "package:base"
```

Agradeço o help.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode especificar de qual pacote usar a função com `::`

```
rgdal::buffer()
raster::buffer()
```

É sempre recomendável de especificar de qual pacote estamos usando a função como mostrado acima.

Além do mais, você pode acessar uma função com o `::` sem carregar o pacote com o `library()`.